# Android application which uses Volley Image Loader and Picasso, it is possible to merge LRU Cache instances?

Tags: android, android-volley, picasso

I have an application which uses both volley image loading libraries and Picasso library (dont ask!).

I trying to refactor to make it only use one library but i have a few questions,

Both libraries use their own LRU cache so i am assuming there are two which both occupy memory. Now is it possible to merge them together, i.e. both use the same LRU cache instance?

Below is my LRU cache code which is from the example used by Volley. Note for Picasso I am using the default instance.

```
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public BitmapLruCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```